# Using .Net Delayed Signing With Digicert Certificate

Tags: .net, signing, assembly-signing, digicert

We have a pfx signing key from digicert that we use as delayed signing, but when we install it on a computer it won't run, unless we add an exclusion for that delayed signing key (sn.exe -Vr *,).  This should be possible, right?  Or am I missing something?  I created a delayed signing key:

```
sn -p d:\DigCert.pfx DelayedSigning.snk
```

And then we use DelayedSigning.snk in C# .net assemblies as delayed signing:
[image]

And then after compiling and obfuscating, we use signtool to sign with the full key:

```
signtool.exe sign /f d:\DigCert.pfx /p ourPW /tr http://timestamp.digicert.com /td sha256 /fd sha256 /a outputPath\*.dll
```

And then like I said, if we try to run on a clean windows 10 OS it won't work unless we add the delayed signing exclusion (sn.exe -Vr *,). Any ideas?

Note: when I run sn -V on one of the assemblies, it says "XXXXX.dll is a delay-signed or test-signed assembly" - how come?

Comment: "but when we install it on a computer it won't run, unless we add an exclusion for that delayed signing key (sn.exe -Vr *,)", but isn't that what delay signing supposed to be?

Comment: You are mixing up two very different signing options.  Delay-signing and sn.exe only applies to the strong name of an assembly, a digicert certificate and signtool.exe only applies to code-signing.  There is no indication that you actually want or need a strong name for the assembly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for responses, yes I finally realized that strong-name signing and code signing are two different things.  Solution is to create a separate signing code for strong signing: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/create-use-strong-named and then create a delayed signing key: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/delay-sign and use this in projects with delayed signing.  Before shipping would sign it with sn.exe with the private strong-name signing key (info in last link).  Then after it's strong name signed, sign with the digicert certificate with signtool.exe.  https://www.digicert.com/kb/code-signing/signcode-signtool-command-line.htm